# Registering components globally in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using `webpack` with `vuejs` and I'm trying to put as much stuff as I can in `vendor.js` so that my `app.js` can be smaller so that `webpack` build time can be reduced.

I'm trying to register Font Awesome vuejs version globally.

in my main.js

```
import Icon from 'vue-awesome';
window.Icon = Icon;
Vue.use(Icon);
```

And in my component `.vue` file I have

```
<template>
    <icon name="beer"></icon>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

    components: {
        Icon: window.Icon
    }

}
</script>
```

And I am getting this error:
`Unknown custom element: <icon> - did you register the component correctly?`

window.Icon is set correctly I can log it, but i think i am doing some rookie mistake here, because when i include it locally in the component directly everything is working.

Comment: Try lower-case "i" for your component name: `icon: window.Icon`

Comment: @RoyJ didn't work :(

Comment: Just looking at `vue-awesome` docs, shouldn't you import Icon in way like this `import Icon from 'vue-awesome/components/Icon.vue'` ?

Comment: You need to do `Vue.use()` within each module.  https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/63

Comment: @RoyJ thanks If you post it as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [in a module environment such as CommonJS, you always need to call
> Vue.use() explicitly](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Using-a-Plugin)

A longer discussion is here: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/63, but the gist is that each module must call `Vue.use()`.

Comment: So it's synonymous with `import`, `include` and `require` constructs from other languages?

Comment: @JaredFarrish no, there are still native js import and require. Vue.use installs a plugin in order to extend Vue functionality.